# My texture won't show up normally when i turn on subdivison

Tags: mesh, texturing, uv

[image] This is what my texture on the pc screen looks like when i turn on subdivision[image] and this is what it looks like without it on

I tried tweaking the mesh or changing the texture, adding image textures, checking if theres somehow something behind the screen popping out, even checking the uv map and messing around with it but i can't seem to find the problem. I'm kind of new to blender and i'm doing it mostly as a hobby so i'd appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: maybe in the settings of the Subdivision Surface modifier > Advanced > UV Smooth > try Keep Corners? Or please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I tried the first thing but it sadly didn't work. https://pasteall.org/blend/9424e846b1534df381321213bfa909b2 is the link for my blend file download. Thank you for your help

Comment: these lines are made with edges, if you remove them it will delete them, is it what you want or do you want to keep them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have overlapping edges, it creates these lines once you enable the *Subdivision Surface* modifier because for some reasons you've assigned the other material to the faces it has created. To remove them, just select all and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked!! I'm not quite sure how i managed to make that mistake but it's whatever now. Thank you!